# Custom overflowHandler implementation in ExtJS 4

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have panel with two `toolbars`. How can I to implement custom class for using as `overflowHandler`, which will move components to second toolbar on first toolbar's overflow?

I tried to use code of `Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu`, but my second toolbar simply hides.

Here is my code, which was mixed with `toolbar overflow` example from `ExtJS 4` distributive.

```
Ext.require(['Ext.window.Window', 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', 'Ext.menu.ColorPicker', 'Ext.form.field.Date']);
Ext.onReady(function(){

    /**
     * Override for implementing tbar2 
     */
    Ext.override(Ext.panel.Panel, {
        bridgeToolbars : function () {
            var toolbar;
            this.callParent(arguments);
            if (this.tbar2) {
                if (Ext.isArray(this.tbar2)) {
                    toolbar = {
                        xtype : 'toolbar',
                        items : this.tbar2
                    };
                }
                else if (!toolbar.xtype) {
                    toolbar.xtype = 'toolbar';
                }
                toolbar.dock = 'top';
                toolbar.isTbar2 = true;
                this.dockedItems = this.dockedItems.concat(toolbar);
                this.tbar2 = null;
            }
        },
        onRender       : function () {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            var topBars = this.getDockedItems('toolbar[dock="top"]'),
                i,
                len;
            for (i = 0, len = topBars.length; i < len; i++) {
                if (topBars[i].isTbar2) {
                    this.tbar2 = topBars[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        /**
         * Lazy creates new toolbar and returns it
         * @param {Ext.panel.Panel} panel
         * @param {String} position
         * @return {Ext.toolbar.Toolbar}
         */
        getDynamicTBar : function (position) {
            var panel = this,
                params,
                tb;
            position = position || 'top';
            if (position === 'tbar2') {
                tb = panel.tbar2;
                params = {dock : 'top', isTbar2 : true};
            }
            else {
                tb = panel.getDockedItems('toolbar[dock="' + position + '"]');
                params = {dock : position};
                if (tb.length > 0) {
                    tb = tb[0];
                }
            }
            if (!tb) {
                console.log('created tb at ' + position);
                tb = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', params);
                panel.addDocked(tb);
            }
            return tb;
        }
    });

    Ext.define('Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.TBar2', {
        extend : 'Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.None',

        constructor : function () {
            this.tbar2Items = [];
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        },

        beginLayout : function (ownerContext) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            this.clearOverflow(ownerContext);
        },

        beginLayoutCycle : function (ownerContext, firstCycle) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            if (!firstCycle) {
                this.clearOverflow(ownerContext);
                this.layout.cacheChildItems(ownerContext);
            }
        },

        getOverflowCls : function () {
            return Ext.baseCSSPrefix + this.layout.direction + '-box-overflow-body';
        },

        _asLayoutRoot : { isRoot : true },

        clearOverflow : function () {
            if (this.tbar2) {
                this.tbar2.suspendLayouts();
                this.tbar2.hide();
                this.tbar2.resumeLayouts(this._asLayoutRoot);
            }
            this.tbar2Items.length = 0;
        },

        handleOverflow : function (ownerContext) {

            var me = this,
                layout = me.layout,
                owner = layout.owner,
                names = layout.getNames(),
                startProp = names.x,
                sizeProp = names.width,
                plan = ownerContext.state.boxPlan,
                available = plan.targetSize[sizeProp],
                childItems = ownerContext.childItems,
                len = childItems.length,
                childContext,
                comp, i, props,
                tbarOwner = owner.ownerCt;
            owner.suspendLayouts();
            // Hide all items which are off the end, and store them to allow them to be restored
            // before each layout operation.
            me.tbar2Items.length = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                childContext = childItems[i];
                props = childContext.props;
                if (props[startProp] + props[sizeProp] > available) {
                    comp = childContext.target;
                    me.tbar2Items.push(comp);
                    owner.remove(comp, false);
                }
            }
            owner.resumeLayouts();
            if (!me.tbar2 && (tbarOwner instanceof Ext.panel.Panel)) {
                me.tbar2 = tbarOwner.getDynamicTBar('tbar2');
            }
            me.tbar2.suspendLayouts();
            me.tbar2.show();

            Ext.each(me.tbar2Items, function(item, index) {
                me.tbar2.add(item);
            });
            me.tbar2.resumeLayouts(me._asLayoutRoot);
        }

    });


    var handleAction = function(action){
        Ext.example.msg('<b>Action</b>', 'You clicked "' + action + '"');
    };

    var colorMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.ColorPicker', {
        handler: function(cm, color){
            Ext.example.msg('Color Selected', '<span style="color:#' + color + ';">You choose {0}.</span>', color);
        }
    });

    var showDate = function(d, value) {
        Ext.example.msg('<b>Action date</b>', 'You picked ' + Ext.Date.format(value, d.format));
    };

    var fromPicker = false;

    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title: 'Standard',
        closable: false,
        height:250,
        width: 500,
        bodyStyle: 'padding:10px',
        contentEl: 'content',
        autoScroll: true,
        tbar: Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
            layout: {
                overflowHandler: 'TBar2'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype:'splitbutton',
                text: 'Menu Button',
                iconCls: 'add16',
                handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Menu Button'),
                menu: [{text: 'Menu Item 1', handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Menu Item 1')}]
            },'-',{
                xtype:'splitbutton',
                text: 'Cut',
                iconCls: 'add16',
                handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Cut'),
                menu: [{text: 'Cut menu', handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Cut menu')}]
            },{
                text: 'Copy',
                iconCls: 'add16',
                handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Copy')
            },{
                text: 'Paste',
                iconCls: 'add16',
                menu: [{text: 'Paste menu', handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Paste menu')}]
            },'-',{
                text: 'Format',
                iconCls: 'add16',
                handler: Ext.Function.pass(handleAction, 'Format')
            },'->', {
                fieldLabel: 'Action',
                labelWidth: 70,
                width: 180,
                xtype: 'datefield',
                labelSeparator: '',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    expand: function(){
                        fromPicker = true;
                    },
                    collapse: function(){
                        fromPicker = false;  
                    },
                    change: function(d, newVal, oldVal) {
                        if (fromPicker || !d.isVisible()) {
                            showDate(d, newVal);
                        }
                    },
                    keypress: {
                        buffer: 500,
                        fn: function(field){
                            var value = field.getValue();
                            if (value !== null && field.isValid()) {
                                showDate(field, value);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Sell',
                iconCls: 'money-down',
                enableToggle: true,
                toggleHandler: function(button, pressed) {
                    Ext.example.msg('<b>Action</b>', 'Right ToggleButton ' + (pressed ? 'Buy' : 'Sell'));
                    button.setText(pressed ? 'Buy' : 'Sell')
                    button.setIconCls(pressed ? 'money-up' : 'money-down')
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Choose a Color',
                menu: colorMenu // <-- submenu by reference
            }]
        })
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: what exact version r u using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to implement overflowHandler for toolbar layout, which will add second toolbar and wraps components from first toolbar to second when them cannot be displayed because there isn't enough width of toolbar's container.
First, we need to override Ext.panel.Panel:

```
Ext4.override(Ext4.panel.Panel, {
    bridgeToolbars: function () {
        var toolbar;
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if (this.tbar2) {
            if (Ext4.isArray(this.tbar2)) {
                toolbar = {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: this.tbar2
                };
            } else if (!toolbar.xtype) {
                toolbar.xtype = 'toolbar';
            }
            toolbar.dock = 'top';
            toolbar.isTbar2 = true;
            this.dockedItems = this.dockedItems.concat(toolbar);
            this.tbar2 = null;
        }
    },
    onRender: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var topBars = this.getDockedItems('toolbar[dock="top"]'),
            i,
            len;
        for (i = 0, len = topBars.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (topBars[i].isTbar2) {
                this.tbar2 = topBars[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    /**
     * Creates, if not exists, and returns toolbar at passed position
     * @param {Ext.panel.Panel} panel
     * @param {String} position
     * @return {Ext.toolbar.Toolbar}
     */
    getDynamicTBar: function (position) {
        var panel = this,
            params,
            tb;
        position = position || 'top';
        if (position === 'tbar2') {
            tb = panel.tbar2;
            params = {
                dock: 'top',
                isTbar2: true,
                layout: {
                    overflowHandler: 'Scroller'
                }
            };
        } else {
            tb = panel.getDockedItems('toolbar[dock="' + position + '"]');
            params = {
                dock: position
            };
            if (tb.length > 0) {
                tb = tb[0];
            }
        }
        if (!tb) {
            tb = Ext4.create('Ext4.toolbar.Toolbar', params);
            panel.addDocked(tb);
            if (position === 'tbar2') {
                panel.tbar2 = tb;
            }
        }
        return tb;
    }
});
```

Next, we need to create class Ext4.layout.container.boxOverflow.TBar2 (it has so long name because ExtJS searches handleOverflow (which is instance of String) in hardcoded Ext4.layout.container.boxOverflow namespace).

```
/**
 * @class Ext4.layout.container.boxOverflow.TBar2
 * Class for using as overflowHandler
 * @extends Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.None
 */
Ext4.define('Ext4.layout.container.boxOverflow.TBar2', {
    extend: 'Ext4.layout.container.boxOverflow.None',

    /**
     * @private
     * @property {Boolean} initialized
     */
    initialized: false,

    constructor: function () {
        /**
         * @private
         * @property {Array} tbar2Items
         * List of moved components
         */
        this.tbar2Items = [];
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    beginLayout: function (ownerContext) {
        if (!this.initialized) {
            this.layout.owner.ownerCt.on('afterlayout', this.createTBar2, this);
            this.initialized = true;
        }
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.clearOverflow(ownerContext);
    },

    beginLayoutCycle: function (ownerContext, firstCycle) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        if (!firstCycle) {
            this.clearOverflow(ownerContext);
            this.layout.cacheChildItems(ownerContext);
        }
    },

    getOverflowCls: function () {
        return Ext4.baseCSSPrefix + this.layout.direction + '-box-overflow-body';
    },

    /**
     * @private
     * @property {Object} _asLayoutRoot
     */
    _asLayoutRoot: {
        isRoot: true
    },

    clearOverflow: function () {
        // If afterlayout is not processing and tbar2 already created,
        // we can to move components from tbar2 to first toolbar, because now
        // there isn't any overflow
        if (!this.processing && this.tbar2) {
            this.tbar2.items.each(function (item) {
                this.tbar1.add(item);
                // change ui from saved property, or CSS will be incorrect
                item.ui = item.origUI;
            }, this);
            this.tbar2.removeAll(false);
            this.tbar2.hide();
        }
        this.tbar2Items.length = 0;
    },

    /**
     * @private
     * Creates tbar2 and does other routines
     */
    createTBar2: function () {
        // if afterlayout event is still processing,
        // or we don't need to handle toolbar overflow, just return from function
        if (this.processing || !this.doTbar2) {
            return;
        }
        this.processing = true;
        this.doTbar2 = false;
        var me = this,
            ownerContext = this.mOwnerContext,
            layout = me.layout,
            owner = layout.owner,
            names = layout.getNames(),
            startProp = names.x,
            sizeProp = names.width,
            plan = ownerContext.state.boxPlan,
            available = plan.targetSize[sizeProp],
            childItems = ownerContext.childItems,
            len = childItems.length,
            childContext,
            comp, i, props,
            tbarOwner = owner.ownerCt;

        me.tbar1 = owner;
        // save components which will be moved
        owner.suspendLayouts();
        me.tbar2Items.length = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            childContext = childItems[i];
            props = childContext.props;
            if (props[startProp] + props[sizeProp] > available) {
                comp = childContext.target;
                me.tbar2Items.push(comp);
                // save original ui property
                comp.origUI = comp.ui;
                owner.remove(comp, false);
            }
        }
        owner.resumeLayouts();

        // add tbar2 to the layout cycle (you can see very similar code in clearOverflow
        // method of Ext.layout.container.boxOverflow.Menu)
        tbarOwner.suspendLayouts();
        me.tbar2 = tbarOwner.getDynamicTBar('tbar2');
        me.tbar2.show();
        // moving components
        Ext4.each(me.tbar2Items, function (item, index) {
            me.tbar2.insert(index, item);
            item.ui = item.origUI;
        });
        tbarOwner.resumeLayouts(this._asLayoutRoot);
        this.processing = false;
    },

    handleOverflow: function (ownerContext) {
        // set flag and store context for later using
        this.doTbar2 = true;
        this.mOwnerContext = ownerContext;
    }

});
```

Please note I use ExtJS 4 bootstrapping (because in my web app there is ExtJD 2.3 too), so in your code you must probably use `Ext.` instead of `Ext4.`